# execute part of string as code pandas/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

This is the sample string value in a pandas df column :

```
'Had {0} {1} in {2}.format(num_of_persons,type_of_person,date)'
```

I want to extract the code part starting at '.format()' and input the values in the string where it would look something like this:

```
num_of_persons='20'
type_of_person ='patients'
date='2020-04'

text='Had {0} {1} in {2}'.format(num_of_persons,type_of_person,date)
```

I want to extract and output like this in the pandas df column  :

```
 'Had 20 patients in 2020-04'
```

I tried splitting the string at '.' but unsure how to convert the second half into code and not the string that will execute.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where do you have a pandas df column? All I see is three local variables. Please make examples relevant to your problem.

Comment: do the strings `num_of_persons` etc refer to local variables? are there more than three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
foo, bar = col.split(".")
exec(f"text  = '{foo}'.{bar}")
```

exec() is used for running code in a string.

Comment: Does 'text' in this case then contain 'Had {0} {1} in {2}'.format(num_of_persons,type_of_person,date) or would it contain 'Had 20 patients in 2020-04' ?

Comment: It contains the formatted String, you cannont change the variables after that, without recalling exec()

Answer (score 0):

Try with `apply`

```
df['out'] = df.apply(lambda x : 'Had {0} {1} in {2}'.format(x['c1'],x['c2'],x['c3']),axis=1)
```